# Глубина и высота поддерева

Tags: c, дерево, алгоритм, c++

В чем разница между глубиной и высотой поддерева? Не могли бы привести пример алгоритма поиска глубины и высоты поддерева.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну собственно:

- глубина поддерева - расстояние от корня дерева до корня поддерева
- высота поддерева - длина самой длинной ветви в этом поддереве; где длина ветви поддерева это расстояние от корня поддерева до листа этой ветви; лист соответвтенно узел дерева не имеющий потомков)

Answer (score 5):

Алгоритм поиска высоты.

```
int HeightOfTree(BinaryTreeNode * node)
{
    if(node == 0)
        return 0;
    int left, right;
    if (node->leftChild != NULL) {
        left = HeightOfTree(node->leftChild);
    }else 
        left = -1;
    if (node->rightChild != NULL) {
        right = HeightOfTree(node->rightChild);
    }else 
        right = -1;
    int max = left > right ? left : right;
    return max+1;

}
```

Алгоритм поиска глубины.

```
int DepthOfTree(BinaryTreeNode * node)
{
    if(node->parent == NULL)
        return 0;
    return 1+DepthOfTree(node->parent);       
}
```