# Как найти высоту бинарного дерева не используя узлы (на массивах)?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, бинарное-дерево

Я делал на узлах, но по времени не проходит.

```
int height(struct Node *root){
    if (root == NULL){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 + max(height(root -> left), height(root -> right));
}
```

Comment: Приведите полное условие задачи. Это явно кусок чего-то. А этого чего-то зависит правильное решение.

Comment: Не проходит не из-за узлов.

Comment: Вот тут искали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0

Answer (score -1):

В классической реализации на массиве подразумевается, что дерево уже сбалансировано. В таком случае его высота log(n)

Answer (score -1):

Судя по "не проходит по времени" у вас какая-то олимпиадная задача. В таком случае довавьте поле "высота узла" в узел, и при вставке/удалении узла обновляйте необходимые поля. Обновление в сбалансированном дереве займет то же O(log N), что и вставка, так что ничего во времени вы не теряете, зато высоту дерева получаете за O(1).